# Model performance of cumulated model output

Tags: predictive-models

Engineer here, excuse my lack of knowledge in statistic terminology. It's a rather basic question I guess. I just need a nudge into the right direction to look it up myself. Prior searching sessions weren't fruitful.
I have the following question:

1. I have a multivariate linear model that estimates energy consumption on a daily basis.
2. It's based of physical parameters with random noise. Mostly normally distributed.
3. The residual of the model follows a normal distribution.

What matters for me is monthly consumption. I want to estimate the model performance (R^2, etc.) for monthly cumulated values. In my understanding summing the daily values up to a monthly sum should cancel out some of the noise and increase model performance.

Edit: concrete question: How do I calculate model performance for aggregated values based on individual value model performance?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: From your model calculate predicted values per month, and compare those with actual monthly consumption? Maybe present for us a plot of those values?